# Simulating Keypress in Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Used the carbon layer before to simulate key presses, but since sandboxing the app, that isn't possible anymore.

Does anyone know of a alternative, or maybe how we can "temporary except" this carbon function from the sandbox ?

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The purpose of the sandbox is, in part, to prevent your application from interacting with other applications, and simulating keyboard input would affect other applications.